# Android Chrome Webview access to Google Pay is not working

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview, stripe-payments, google-pay

Trying to integrate Google Pay (via Stripe) in our App.
On Android 7.0, the native chrome browser is able to get access to the Google Pay data and display the stored cards in G-pay
But when we try to access the same from inside the Chrome Webview we are launching as part of a test Android App, it is unable to fetch the G-pay data.

Is it a limitation or a bug?

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: My understanding is it is a limitation inside a web view. If you need to use Google Pay via a mobile app, you should use a Native implementation (https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/google-pay) or use a browser intent from your Android app to open the main (Chrome) browser: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Browser

Comment: @duck your answer is correct and in-line with my suspicion. Perhaps you can edit it so I can accept it as an answer? The other option I would like to try is chrome custom tabs - https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs Do you think it could work?

Comment: Ah neat, my guess is custom tabs will probably work as its launching chrome proper, but to know for sure i might try to open a page with the payment request button (even using their demo app https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use Google Pay via a mobile app, you should use a native implementation, such as that [offered by Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/google-pay), or use a [browser intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Browser) from your Android app to open the mobile Chrome browser

Just as a note, something similar happens with Apple Pay; Apple allows you to use a native implementation in an app, or web-based Apple Pay with mobile [Safari or SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web), but not more restrictive web views.